# What HTTP response status code to return for the list of child items when parent does not exist?

Tags: http-status-code-404, httpresponse

What is the correct response status code for getting the list of child items by the ID of a parent, if parent does not exist? E.g. getting a list if orders placed by a customer: `/customers/{id}/orders`. If the customer with the passed ID exists but has no orders, the answer seems simple - return `200` and an empty array. But what if the customer does not exist? Should the response be the same, or a `404`?

To make it more interesting, consider getting a list of customer orders that contain a certain product: `/customers/{id}/orders?productId={productId}`. If the customer exists but never ordered the product - return `200` and an empty array. But what if the product does not exist - `200` or `404`?